# how to test a cascade delete with Rspec

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

for my Rails 4 app, I want to test that deleting a Course object deletes associated Chapter objects.

There, on my Course model I defined the assiociation as follows:

```
has_many :chapters, dependent: :delete_all
```

This works fine. However, I can't figure out how to write a test for this cascaded delete.

My Rspec test looks like this:

```
before do
    @course = Fabricate(:course)
end
it "deletes associated chapters" do
  set_current_admin
  chapter1 = Fabricate(:chapter, course_id: @course_id)
  delete :destroy, id: @course.id
  expect(Chapter.count).to eq(0)
end
```

I would expect Chapter.all to be 0 but when I run this test, I get this result:

```
1) Admin::CoursesController DELETE #destroy deletes associated chapters
 Failure/Error: expect(Chapter.all).to eq(0)

   expected: 0
        got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Chapter id: 709, title: "omnis corrupti eos et   aperiam", description: "Alias sunt tempore aut deserunt. Optio ea assumenda...", course_id: nil, created_at: "2013-11-01 07:10:28", updated_at: "2013-11-01 07:10:28", tagline: "Omnis nemo praesentium corporis. Doloremque dolorib...", badge_image: nil>]>

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/controllers/admin/courses_controller_spec.rb:181:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How can I make this test pass?

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

`Chapter.all` is a method of ActiveRecord::Relation (Rails 4) and it does not return a number.

You would like to test the count so use `Chapter.count`

Comment: I add some explanation to the answer

Comment: thanks for the help gotva. I use Chapter.count now, but my test is still failing, saying it got 0 but inspected 1

Comment: Try to perform `rake test:prepare` (it seems you have not cleared test DB)

Comment: already synced my test database with the development. Ran rake db:test:prepare again, just to make sure, but it didn't solve the issue. My test is still not passing, saying it expected 0 but got 1

Comment: it seems to me that you build incorrect parameters. You can compare a list of them in `development.log` and `test.log` I can assume that params should be `course: {id: @course.id}`

Answer (score 0):

It's not RSpec, but the following may provide some motivation.

```
test 'authentication - dependent destroy' do
  user = users(:adam)
  authentication = user.authentications.first
  user.destroy
  assert_nil Authentication.find_by_id(authentication.id)
end
```